# htmlagilitypack InnerText bug

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse a website and get some content. This is my code :

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='article-content']").InnerText
```

I just need text but the result is something like this :
  some text... and this array :

```
( [0] => 39 [1] => 6 [2] => 10 [3] => 9 [4] => 13 [5] => 5 [6] => 7 [7] => 12 [8] => 11 [9] => 8 [10] => 14 [11] => 82 ) [archtoday] => 0 [hour] => 09:00 [autoarchive] => 1 [autoarchivereset] => 1 [show_description] => 0 [num_desc_words] => 10 [show_description_image] => 0 [num_leading_articles] => 0
```

I've tried:

```
HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='article-content']").InnerText)
```

But the result is same 
link : http://www.interpressnews.ge/ge/politika/353565-barak-obamas-thanashemtse-rusethma-saqarthveloshi-gankhorcielebuli-intervenciis-dros-mighebuli-gakvethilebi-aithvisa.html

div :

```
<div class="article-content">
```

Comment: Please look at the preview while you are writing your post, and use the formatting tools provided. Right now it's extremely difficult to see what you're getting or what you want, or even to edit your post into shape. If you [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33628199/edit) then maybe someone can help.

Comment: I don't see any JSON here...

Comment: Which part are you referring to as JSON?

Comment: [0] => 39 [1] => 6 [2] => 10 [3] => 9 [4] => 13 [5] => 5 [6] => 7 [7] => 12 [8] => 11 [9] => 8 [10] => 14 [11] => 82 ) [archtoday] => 0 [hour] => 09:00 [autoarchive] => 1 [autoarchivereset] => 1 [show_description] => 0

Comment: This is website content : საინფორმაციო სააგენტო "ინტერპრესნიუსი" მკითხველს სთავაზობს ამომწურავ და მიუკერძოებელ ინფორმაციას საქართველოში და მის ფარგლებს გარეთ განვითარებულ მოვლენებზე. 

 When i parse it There is additional  json or javascript array...  : 
[0] => 39 [1] => 6 [2] => 10 [3] => 9 [4] => 13 [5] => 5 [6] => 7 [7] => 12 [8] => 11 [9] => 8 [10] => 14 [11] => 82 ) [archtoday] => 0 [hour] => 09:00 [autoarchive] => 1 [autoarchivereset] => 1 [show_description] =>

Comment: Are you sure that what you've quoted there isn't actually in the inner text of that node? It may be that it is being hidden by CSS or something else but if that is what is coming out then the most likely explanation is that it is in the code you are looking at. Is the page you are parsing publicly available? If so linking it will allow us to see for sure. Otherwise do a view source and see if that text is in there.

Comment: find div: //div[@class='article-content']   it is public. link : http://www.interpressnews.ge/ge/politika/353565-barak-obamas-thanashemtse-rusethma-saqarthveloshi-gankhorcielebuli-intervenciis-dros-mighebuli-gakvethilebi-aithvisa.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to note about inner text is that it will get you the text content of the node but doesn't care about CSS or anything else that effects how the web page itself appears. This means that if there is a node with `display` css property set to `none` then the HTML parser doesn't care, it will show you the text of that node anyway. This is exactly what is happening here.

http://www.interpressnews.ge/ge/politika/353565-barak-obamas-thanashemtse-rusethma-saqarthveloshi-gankhorcielebuli-intervenciis-dros-mighebuli-gakvethilebi-aithvisa.html is the page you mentioned in comments. If you view the source of the page (ctrl-u in chrome and I think firefox, not sure of a shortcut in IE) then look for `article-content` in the page you will find the article and see that it also has a `<div style="display:none;">` inside it which contains the strange text you are seeing. This is therefore not a bug in the html agility pack.

You will need to analyze the page and write more complex code to work out exactly what you want to extract from the page.